# how do I get the difference between two R named lists?

Tags: r, indexing, list, set

OK, I've got two named lists, one is "expected" and one is "observed". They may be complex in structure, with arbitrary data types. I want to get a new list containing just those elements of the observed list that are different from what's in the expected list. Here's an example:

```
Lexp <- list(a=1, b="two", c=list(3, "four"))
Lobs <- list(a=1, c=list(3, "four"), b="ni")
Lwant <- list(b="ni")
```

Lwant is what I want the result to be. I tried this:

```
> setdiff(Lobs, Lexp)
[[1]]
[1] "ni"
```

Nope, that loses the name, and I don't think setdiff pays attention to the names. Order clearly doesn't matter here, and I don't want *a=1* to match with *b=1*.

Not sure what a good approach is... Something that loops over a list of *names(Lobs)*? Sounds clumsy and non-R-like, although workable... Got any elegant ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

At least in this case

`Lobs[!(Lobs %in% Lexp)]`

gives you what you want.

Comment: I was just using the %in% function yesterday for debugging and was about the recommend that.

Comment: BTW, this is correct, but not for the correct reason. *The names are not used*, it is just the values that are used. So, e.g., if we rename first list to `Lexp <- list(a=1, d="ni", c=list(3, "four"))`, then this answer returns unexpected empty named list, when it should be `list(b = "ni")`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found one slightly obtuse answer, using the *plyr* package:

```
> Lobs[laply(names(Lobs), function(x) !identical(Lobs[[x]], Lexp[[x]]))]
$b
[1] "ni"
```

So, it takes the names of the array from the observed function, uses double-bracket indexing and the identical() function to compare the sub-lists, then uses the binary array that results from laply() to index into the original observed function.

Anyone got a better/cleaner/sexier/faster way?

Comment: You don't need plyr: Lobs[sapply(names(Lobs), function(x) !identical(Lobs[[x]], Lexp[[x]]))]

Comment: .@Harlan - Is it possible to find the percentage difference between two list having same structure? I am trying to compare how much the expected differ from the observed?